# Can some one hack API calls of React Native or any traditional JS Native Apps

Tags: reactjs, api, react-native, proguard, dex2jar

Let say i have a post api call like this

```
fetch('https://mywebsite.com/endpoint/', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    firstParam: 'yourValue',
    secondParam: 'yourOtherValue',
  }),
});
```

can some one decode this android react app via dex2jar and something like this and snipe the apis calls..

how can we secure the api calls via server side auth and also from snipping

Answer (score 0):

Plus someone can always open up the app and take a look at you MAP file and get your keys as well.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible, since your browser will show each call done by your app, using chrome you could openthe chrome dev tools and have a look at the network tab.

However there is many way to protect this (you cannot hide it, but you could definetly protect it from unwanted access), probably the most popular are this two :

- [Cors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)
- [Authorization Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization)`